# How do I solve this Timer Problem in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing an app development course and I absolutely don't understand the problem I have. I used exactly the same code the instructor used but it just won't work. In her code the updateTimer green but mine is not and the Timer.scheduled is not colored either. When I put a objc in front of my func at the bottom it shows me an error.

Thank you for your help!

[image: Mine]

[image: Hers]

Comment: add your code as text.

Comment: you define the updateTimer function in the button click scope.That is the issue.

Comment: Please also add the text of the error message

Comment: Think your curly braces are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- pull the `updateTimer()` method out of `hardnessSelected` so that is on the class level.
- mark `updateTimer()` as `@objc` so that you can create a selector pointing to it.

Comment: Better yet, use the closure version of `Timer`.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. I doubt they've covered closures at this point in the course, though.